# Returning route with a slug, different controller

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

I run into nasty (for me) problem here.I think pasting code might be to overwhelming so Ill try to say what I want to achieve.
On route /{id}/modify I have a form to create address. On submit i want to be redirected to /{id}/addAddress route which is action of different controller. Data from form I'm sending via array, its okay, but how should I go to the addAddress with the slug, i want to pass return a route with /{$id}/addAddress? Well I hope i said it clearly enough, i still find out that quite difficult.

```
if($formAddress->isSubmitted()){
        $post = $formAddress->getData();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("/{id}/addAddress",array("post"=>$post));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So yeah I got it after little diablo 3 relaxing. seems when you want to be redirected to another controller when in

/2/foo

All you need to do is simple

```
 return $this->redirect("bar");
```

and you will be redirected to action of different controller, the return will lead you to

/2/bar

Hope this might help some other noobs like me cheers!